# MySQL query results are inconsistent

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called "transaction" which saves transactions that are made on some payment system.
I wanted to get a daily report for July 2023 (for example) and ran the following query:

```sql
SELECT DAY(CREATED), count(*) FROM `transaction`
WHERE STATUS = 'approved' AND MONTH(CREATED) = 07 AND YEAR(CREATED) = 2023
GROUP BY DAY(CREATED)
```

The results skip some days, for example for the 7th day of the month I get nothing, but when I change the query to:

```sql
SELECT DAY(CREATED), count(*) FROM `transaction`
WHERE STATUS = 'approved' AND MONTH(CREATED) = 07 AND YEAR(CREATED) = 2023 AND DAY(CREATED) = 7
GROUP BY DAY(CREATED);
```

(Basically adding a `DAY(CREATED) = 7` to the query)

It returns the count for the 7th day.

Why is it inconsistent?
How can I work around it in the first query?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
Table structure and data example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL,
  `PLATFORM_ID` int NOT NULL,
  `ENTITY_ID` int NOT NULL,
  `RELATED_TRANSACTION_ID` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ORIGIN_ID` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `BANK` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AMOUNT` double NOT NULL,
  `CURRENCY` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `CREATED` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CARD_NO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CARD_BRAND` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CARD_EXPIRE_YEAR` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `CARD_EXPIRE_MONTH` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HOLDER_NAME` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` enum('approved','declined','filtered','pending') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `IS_3D` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_AT` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `AMOUNTEUR` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `IS_FRAUD` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FRAUD_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `KYC_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Example Insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO `transaction` (`ID`, `PLATFORM_ID`, `ENTITY_ID`, `RELATED_TRANSACTION_ID`, `ORIGIN_ID`, `BANK`, `AMOUNT`, `CURRENCY`, `TYPE`, `CREATED`, `CARD_NO`, `CARD_BRAND`, `CARD_EXPIRE_YEAR`, `CARD_EXPIRE_MONTH`, `HOLDER_NAME`, `EMAIL`, `STATUS`, `IS_3D`, `CREATED_AT`, `AMOUNTEUR`, `IS_FRAUD`, `FRAUD_DATE`, `KYC_DATE`) VALUES
(1, 1, 87, 0, '219114359', 'SOME BANK', 150, 'USD', 'DB', '2022-02-01 00:00:17', '000000XXXXXX0000', 'MasterCard', 2025, '06', 'NAME FAMILY', 'aaaaaaaaa@gmail.com', 'approved', 0, '2022-08-25 13:12:58', 150.7605, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I've emitted the indexes definitions as I assume it should not be relevant in this case.

Comment: Provide sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) which allows to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Does CHECK TABLE reports that there is no errors?

Comment: I think something is limiting the amount of data that you get back. Let's say that you have a total of 2000 rows and the limit is on 1000 rows. If the data regarding day 7 is in the bottom 1000 rows you might miss it. When adding the extra predicate to your query you narrow down the result and therefore you're not hitting the limit. Are you running the query in some kind of application/ui that might have such a limit built in perhaps?

Comment: i'm not quite sure what was the issue, i did a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7mqKwZywwFFbzEeJugJJck/0) and they work as expected. maybe there are more factors in play?

Comment: That single value that you've shared wouldn't return a single result with the given query, as it was not created in 2023 (which is a `WHERE` clause from the query)

Comment: your sample [simply returns empty](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7mqKwZywwFFbzEeJugJJck/1) as expected.. again, reduce the noises, make a smaller test case but add more useful data points.

Comment: @Akina
Check return OK

Comment: @wenzzzel I'm using PhpMyAdmin

Comment: @BagusTesa It might be, I'm trying to understand those factors too, currently I have no clue why it doesn't work

Comment: [tag:phpmyadmin] shouldn't be the source of your woes, though you can always try the `mysql` console.

Comment: @BagusTesa On a small set of test data it worked fine, I have a couple of millions of transactions, I've even tried to introduce a limit with more than all the transactions I've got, but nothing so far.

Comment: *"I have a couple of millions of transactions"* - see Akina's suggestion, make sure the database is healthy. even so, i do curious whether you hit the maximum packet size. anyway, any reporting works should be done in batch (e.g. separated by month) to avoid choking your mysql.

Comment: How many rows/days are returned by the first query? 31,30 or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem after running it in the MySQL console, it was simply because the PhpMyAdmin system was limiting the view only to 25 rows...

It was my mistake! :O
Thank you all for your time much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to hear you found it! Trying to get my reputation up, so would apreciate a lot if you'd upvote my comment where I suggested you check for limits in the client :)

Comment: @wenzzzel comment upvotes don't generate reputation

Comment: No wonder it's so hard to get the reputation up ;) Jokes aside, thanks for letting me know.